# Xcode can't get did registerForRemoteNotifications popup is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

as titled.
Xcode can't get did registerForRemoteNotifications popup is shown, in this case, if I use some preemptive question, or bring user to setting page if he/she has disabled the push notification previously, I can't check if the system popup is shown before hand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself, after 30+ testings with scenarios.

Obviously we can't check the system popup or not, but we can know did the user enabled the permission.  Documents and users on forums often refer to the answer of

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]
```

which is INCORRECT, because no matter did the user grant or reject the permission, this function still return true. this can only prove did the push notification token is given.  Apple's API did a bit messy here.

You may use this function to get the permission granted, in details.
if this function return 0, the user has rejected the grant, or didn't open anything at all even if he/she grant the permission.

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types]
```